# Why are the values incorrect when parsing binary data using python ctype structures?

Tags: python, parsing, binary, ctypes, firmware

[This binary data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJylJ.png) is being parsed via a python parser file containing ctype structures. Unfortunately, it is not returning the proper values. Most likely this is because I am not 100% sure how to interpret this data.

[This spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ailr.png) outlines how the binary data is organized. I am not 100% sure how to interpret this spec.

Here is what my python parser looks like:

```
from binascii import unhexlify
from ctypes import *

data = 'FE A5 11 11 3F A5 A1 A3 FE 9A A5 A4 8E A6 A2 89 A1 FE A3 A5 8A FE A5 A4 A5 35 8A 31 04 3C 07 1E 31 31 7A 59 23 01 4D 5E 11 0E 70 0D 41 64 27 63 57 0F 3A 59 47 29 2A 43 3B 66 02 0A 70 5D 56 5B 01 FE 4E 57 34 65 94 2E 52 66 5A 63 03 50 53 98 4E 6C 35 71 10 7B 57 0F 64 8A 70 4B 61 1B 07 3C 55 7A 46 48 3D 3D 20 02 62 65 69 09 03 3F 40 1D 61 45 22 15 39 42 4E 4C 13 12 1A 6F 59 63 8C 5A 28 67 15 2E 55 2A 59 16 0B 3C 68 08 09 42 1B 2D 0D 4A 0A 2E 82 6A 37 1C 2C 11 54 4E 57 56 25 50 09 17 5F 5F 0C 1E 6A 1F 85 28 5A 08 3B 19 79 65 13 6C 39 15 05 14 23 FE 47 04 32 52 52 61 1B FE 13 2D 40 4C 43 9D 44 78 73 7E 43 35 06 15 5A 67 21 34 4B 58 8E 68 1A 81 4B 24 75 64 50 58 5F 6B 7E 42 5F 8B 56 77 62 05 57 2C 72 53 1E 4A 50 5C 4D 45 1C 63 23 58 53 03 06 34 5A 37 58 44 4A 6C 7A 55 1E 59 66 68 69 05 6E 35 16 35 6C 15 84 1A 72 5A 18 3F 1D 65 7C 38 52 53 43 32 40 2A 6C 4C 77 4D 37 1E 0F 45 19 66 38 21 3D 6B 63 6D 06 37 1E 18 44 32 45 24 05 6E 1E 5C 6B 0D 09 93 1E 30 6E 30 52 D5 1C 6B 63 15 53 27 24 16 1B 16 20 33 7B 40 23 00 38 17 09 68 38 8F 1B 32 75 5F 48 5A 5D 52 45 75 5E 92 15 A3 21 81 1F 51 27 42 93 59 63 44 1D 40 18 05 0E 6A 4D 39 52 6F 53 26 6C 73 0A 10 26 8F 77 30 24 59 1C 66 45 5E 6B 8F 34 73 2A 7B 1F 48 2A 18 54 55 89 6F 58 16 85 4B 07 59 68 2B 3E 89 32 40 5F 81 94 6E 4E 22 99 2C 73 B0 18 7D 2E 3C 49 01 3C 50 97 96 1F 5F 6F 21 67 51 91 3F 2C 61 51 2E 91 48 0D 5F 20 56 2F 20 7E FE FE FE 3E 39 4C 06 24 0F 02 16 47 7C 47 30 FE FE 69 18 17 58 FE 13 28 55 FE 60 01 FE 08 23 0D 23 FE FE FE FE FE FE FE FE 00 00 05 BD 00 00 6C A6'
buffer = unhexlify(datahex.replace(' ',''))

bad_block = 0xFE

def getBlockCountUnion(numBlocks, buffer, version):
    class sysblock_entry_struct(Structure):
        _pack_ = 1
        _fields_ = [("SysBlock", c_uint16),
                    ("SysBlkCnt", c_uint32)]
        def __str__(self):
            retStr = ""
            retStr += "SysBlock: %8.8Xh\n" % self.SysBlock
            retStr += "SysBlkCnt: %8.8Xh\n" % self.SysBlkCnt
            return retStr

    class block_count_struct(Structure):
        _pack_ = 1
        _fields_ = [("Block", c_uint8 * numBlocks),
                    ("GlobalCntOffset", c_uint32),
                    ("GlobalCntOffsetSLC", c_uint32),
                    ("TLCStartBlock", c_uint16),
                    ("SysBlkCntInfo", sysblock_entry_struct * 6)]

        def __str__(self):
            retstr = "Block Count:\n"
            for index, block in enumerate(self.Block):
                blockStr = "0x%d" % block
                if block == bad_block:
                    blockStr = "0 -- (Bad Block)"
                retstr += "Block[" + str(index) + "]: " + blockStr + "\n"
                retstr += "GlobalCntOffset: 0x08X\n" % self.GlobalCntOffset
                retstr += "GlobalCntOffsetSLC: 0x08%X\n" % self.GlobalCntOffsetSLC
                retstr += "SysBlock and SysBlkCnt:\n"
                for idx, itm in enumerate(self.SysBlkCntInfo):
                    retstr += "[%d]:\n%s\n" % (idx, itm)
                return retstr

    block_count_union = type(getUnionFromStruct(block_count_struct()))
    unionType = eval("block_count_%d_union" % version)
```

This is as far as I have been able to go on my own. I am unable to figure out what is wrong. Most likely due to the fact that I am new to working with firmware, binary data, etc. There is no traceback. And at first glance, it looks correct. However, when comparing it to a correct parsed output, it looks like perhaps I am not parsing correctly due to reading from incorrect locations in the buffer. Maybe there is an offset I am not considering?

This is a sample of the correct output:

> ```
>     ---------SLC Block---------
>     FBlock= 0001(0x0001)    Count= 27979
>     FBlock= 0002(0x0002)    Count= 27831 -- Min Erase Cnt(SLC)
>     FBlock= 0003(0x0003)    Count= 27831 -- Min Erase Cnt(SLC)
>     FBlock= 0004(0x0004)    Count= 27877
>     FBlock= 0005(0x0005)    Count= 27979
>     FBlock= 0006(0x0006)    Count= 27975
>     FBlock= 0007(0x0007)    Count= 27977
>     FBlock= 0008(0x0008)    Count= 0000 -- Bad Block
>     FBlock= 0009(0x0009)    Count= 27968
>     FBlock= 0010(0x000A)    Count= 27979
>     ...
>     ...
>     ...
>     FBlock= 0024(0x0018)    Count= 27979
>     FBlock= 0025(0x0019)    Count= 27867
>     FBlock= 0026(0x001A)    Count= 27952
>     ---------TLC Block---------
>     FBlock= 0027(0x001B)    Count= 1518
>     FBlock= 0028(0x001C)    Count= 1473
>     FBlock= 0029(0x001D)    Count= 1529
>     ...
>     ...
>     ...
>     FBlock= 0494(0x01EE)    Count= 1482
>     FBlock= 0495(0x01EF)    Count= 1504
>     FBlock= 0496(0x01F0)    Count= 0000 -- Bad Block
>     FBlock= 0497(0x01F1)    Count= 0000 -- Bad Block
>     FBlock= 0498(0x01F2)    Count= 0000 -- Bad Block
>     FBlock= 0499(0x01F3)    Count= 0000 -- Bad Block
>     FBlock= 0500(0x01F4)    Count= 0000 -- Bad Block
>     FBlock= 0501(0x01F5)    Count= 0000 -- Bad Block
>     FBlock= 0502(0x01F6)    Count= 0000 -- Bad Block
>     FBlock= 0503(0x01F7)    Count= 0000 -- Bad Block
>     GlobalCntOffset= 0x5BD(1469)
>     GlobalCntOffset_SLC= 0x6CA6(27814)
>     System Block 0 Count = 0x0(0)
>     System Block 1 Count = 0x0(0)
>     System Block 2 Count = 0x2(2)
>     System Block 3 Count = 0x2(2)
>     System Block 4 Count = 0x4B(75)
>     System Block 5 Count = 0x42(66)
> ```

This is a sample of my output:

> ```
>     Block[0]: 0 -- (Bad Block)
>     Block[1]: 0x165
>     Block[2]: 0x17
>     Block[3]: 0x17
>     Block[4]: 0x63
>     Block[5]: 0x165
>     Block[6]: 0x161
>     Block[7]: 0x163
>     Block[8]: 0 -- (Bad Block)
>     Block[9]: 0x154
>     Block[10]: 0x165
>     ...
>     ...
>     ...
>     Block[24]: 0x165
>     Block[25]: 0x53
>     Block[26]: 0x138
>     Block[27]: 0x49
>     Block[28]: 0x4
>     Block[29]: 0x60
>     ...
>     ...
>     ...
>     Block[494]: 0x13
>     Block[495]: 0x35
>     Block[496]: 0 -- (Bad Block)
>     Block[497]: 0 -- (Bad Block)
>     Block[498]: 0 -- (Bad Block)
>     Block[499]: 0 -- (Bad Block)
>     Block[500]: 0 -- (Bad Block)
>     Block[501]: 0 -- (Bad Block)
>     Block[502]: 0 -- (Bad Block)
>     Block[503]: 0 -- (Bad Block)
>     GlobalCntOffset:    0xBD050000
>     GlobalCntOffsetSLC: 0xA66C0000
>     SysBlock and SysBlkEraseCnt:
>     [0]:
>     SysBlock: 00000000h
>     SysBlkCnt: 00000000h
>     [1]:
>     SysBlock: 00000000h
>     SysBlkCnt: 00000000h
>     [2]:
>     SysBlock: 00000000h
>     SysBlkCnt: 00000002h
>     [3]:
>     SysBlock: 00000200h
>     SysBlkCnt: 00000000h
>     [4]:
>     SysBlock: 0000004Bh
>     SysBlkCnt: 42000000h
>     [5]:
>     SysBlock: 00000000h
>     SysBlkCnt: 00000000h
> ```

Just from comparing the values for `GlobalCntOffset` and `GlobalCntOffset_SLC` from my output and the correct output, you can see that I have the right values in there, but in the wrong order and slightly off. I feel like I am very close, but I can't quite get it lined up.

**Side Note:**

SLC Global Count offset is 0x1FC~0x1FF (4 byte)

TLC Global Count offset is 0x1F8~0x1FB (4 byte)

From offset 0~0x1F7, **each byte** means the count for each super block.

If the block count value is `0xFE` (such as Block 0, 1, 8...) then they will be marked as bad block.

For example:

- SLC: SLC block 4, count = offset 0x04 (0xad) + `SLC Global Count (0x24e7)` = 0x2594 (9620)
- TLC: TLC block 22, count = offset 0x16 (0x59) + `TLC Global Count (0x0221)` = 0x27A (634)

**Binary Data:**

```
00000000 FE A5 11 11 3F A5 A1 A3 FE 9A A5 A4 8E A6 A2 89
00000010 A1 FE A3 A5 8A FE A5 A4 A5 35 8A 31 04 3C 07 1E
00000020 31 31 7A 59 23 01 4D 5E 11 0E 70 0D 41 64 27 63
00000030 57 0F 3A 59 47 29 2A 43 3B 66 02 0A 70 5D 56 5B
00000040 01 FE 4E 57 34 65 94 2E 52 66 5A 63 03 50 53 98
00000050 4E 6C 35 71 10 7B 57 0F 64 8A 70 4B 61 1B 07 3C
00000060 55 7A 46 48 3D 3D 20 02 62 65 69 09 03 3F 40 1D
00000070 61 45 22 15 39 42 4E 4C 13 12 1A 6F 59 63 8C 5A
00000080 28 67 15 2E 55 2A 59 16 0B 3C 68 08 09 42 1B 2D
00000090 0D 4A 0A 2E 82 6A 37 1C 2C 11 54 4E 57 56 25 50
000000a0 09 17 5F 5F 0C 1E 6A 1F 85 28 5A 08 3B 19 79 65
000000b0 13 6C 39 15 05 14 23 FE 47 04 32 52 52 61 1B FE
000000c0 13 2D 40 4C 43 9D 44 78 73 7E 43 35 06 15 5A 67
000000d0 21 34 4B 58 8E 68 1A 81 4B 24 75 64 50 58 5F 6B
000000e0 7E 42 5F 8B 56 77 62 05 57 2C 72 53 1E 4A 50 5C
000000f0 4D 45 1C 63 23 58 53 03 06 34 5A 37 58 44 4A 6C
00000100 7A 55 1E 59 66 68 69 05 6E 35 16 35 6C 15 84 1A
00000110 72 5A 18 3F 1D 65 7C 38 52 53 43 32 40 2A 6C 4C
00000120 77 4D 37 1E 0F 45 19 66 38 21 3D 6B 63 6D 06 37
00000130 1E 18 44 32 45 24 05 6E 1E 5C 6B 0D 09 93 1E 30
00000140 6E 30 52 D5 1C 6B 63 15 53 27 24 16 1B 16 20 33
00000150 7B 40 23 00 38 17 09 68 38 8F 1B 32 75 5F 48 5A
00000160 5D 52 45 75 5E 92 15 A3 21 81 1F 51 27 42 93 59
00000170 63 44 1D 40 18 05 0E 6A 4D 39 52 6F 53 26 6C 73
00000180 0A 10 26 8F 77 30 24 59 1C 66 45 5E 6B 8F 34 73
00000190 2A 7B 1F 48 2A 18 54 55 89 6F 58 16 85 4B 07 59
000001a0 68 2B 3E 89 32 40 5F 81 94 6E 4E 22 99 2C 73 B0
000001b0 18 7D 2E 3C 49 01 3C 50 97 96 1F 5F 6F 21 67 51
000001c0 91 3F 2C 61 51 2E 91 48 0D 5F 20 56 2F 20 7E FE
000001d0 FE FE 3E 39 4C 06 24 0F 02 16 47 7C 47 30 FE FE
000001e0 69 18 17 58 FE 13 28 55 FE 60 01 FE 08 23 0D 23
000001f0 FE FE FE FE FE FE FE FE 00 00 05 BD 00 00 6C A6
00000200
```

Comment: What *Python* version are you using, on what *OS*/architecture?

Comment: @CristiFati Python 2.7.11 on Windows 7

Comment: Do you have either or both of those attachments in some textual form? Even a page of html for the table might be useful.

Comment: @BillBell how do you recommend I do that for the binary? I only have a .bin file and the screenshot of it. I'm not sure if there's a way to attach the .bin file to this post. Also, if I try to just copy paste the contents, it just shows the encrypted gibberish.

Comment: Any more details about the device (where there could be a clearer spec)? Where does the correct output come from (some sample app that came with the device)? Also the hex data from the attached pic is the binary data that produces the desired output? As for adding the file, you could (using *Python*) read its content (in binary mode) and post its `repr` in the question.

Comment: Good idea on CristiFati's part. I'm actually more interested in the format information.

Comment: the device is an ssd. there isn't a clearer spec available. the correct output came from software designed to test ssd's. the binary data is the output of a function, and the python parser file just makes that binary data output readable by humans. I found a converter online for the binary data. It was somewhat decent (I had to make some corrections, hopefully I caught them all). I'm adding the textual version of the binary it produced to the question now.

Comment: the binary data is the output of a function that was sent down to the ssd**

Comment: Damn it! I can't see the correspondence between the binary data and correct output...

Comment: @CristiFati Look at Block 4 in the correct output. It is an SLC block. This means that block 4 is offset by GlobalCntOffsetSLC. Mine is incorrect becuase it doesn't include the offset in the Block 4 value. In the binary, Block 4 is on the first row. It is value 0x3F. In the binary, the Global SLC Offset is on the last row. It is value 0x6CA6. The correct output is the sum of SLC Block 4 and the Global SLC offset --> 0x3F + 0x6CA6 = 27877 (in decimal form). My output only has Block 4 as 0x3F (which is half right), but if I were to add the Global SLC offset, it would be correct.

Comment: @CristiFati I am having trouble parsing it so that all the blocks have their proper global offsets added to it. I know whether or not the block is SLC or TLC based on the field in the struct denoting the TLC start block. Every block before the TLC start block should have the SLC Global offset added to it. Everything from the TLC block and after it should have the other Global offset added to it.

Comment: There are a number of typos in the code and data and missing information.  There are Os instead of zeros in the data, and missing quotes and parentheses in the code.  Did you manually type all that in?? The function `getUnionFromStruct` doesn't exist.  Please cut-n-paste your actual code that generates your "bad" output.  Make it a working example.  As is, it doesn't generate any output.  How is the Union instantiated?  What are the values for `numBlocks`, `buffer`, and `version`?  FYI, it looks like the data is big endian, so consider using `ctypes.BigEndianStructure`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I downloaded a hex editor so I was able to get all accurate binary data. I have added it to the question for your reference. But if you take a look at the last two comments I made, you'll see that the main problem is that I am trying to figure out how to parse it so that the first chunk of blocks is adding the Global SLC offset and the last chunk of blocks is adding the regular Global offset. And yes, I manually typed all that in.

Comment: I see how to fix the problem, but couldn't get your code to run (even after fixing typos, which answers shouldn't have to do), and it doesn't generate the incorrect output because it is missing code.  It also seems to be missing data, as `TLCStartBlock` occurs after `GlobalCntOffsetSLC` and the latter is the last data in your data block hex dump, so I wouldn't know when to stop adding `GlobalCntOffset_SLC` to the blocks and switch to `GlobalCntOffset`.  Add the exact code you are using via cut-n-paste that generates your incorrect output (see the [mcve] guidelines), and I think I could fix it.